# password history counts current effective password?

Tags: active-directory, opendj

LDAP/AD has a password policy which can enforce password history.

But does the password history include current effective password as one of history password ?

Question: 
1. does AD record the current effective password to password history ?
2. As I know, OpenDJ will not record current password to history. why

Answer (score 0):

Question 2: password history is a mechanism to track the passwords has used to prevent him to reuse one of the N recents passwords as the service (or administrator) is forcing him to change its password after a certain amount of time. The current password is never in the history, since the history represents the previous passwords, not the one which is used to authenticate the user.
OpenDJ doesn't enable password history by default, because the OpenDJ product is used in many different contexts but very often in Customer Identity facing scenarios, where forcing users to change their passwords every N months is not a best practice and therefore preventing them to reuse the previous password then is unnecessary.
Note that the latest revision of the NIST recommendations for passwords, says that forcing password changes after N months is not the best practice anymore, as it leads users to use passwords easy to remember and to guess, or to write them done on PostIt notes (since there are changed frequently, and thus too easy to forget). Instead NIST recommends that services require a longer password but to only change it if there's a risk of it being compromised.

Comment: Thanks Ludovic. I can understand OpenDj's behavior. Do you happen to know the behavior in Active Directory ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't, but I would assume it's pretty similar and based on the ideas laid out in the LDAP Password Policy Internet Draft.